# How to draw lines properly between nested nodes using tikzpicture and chessboard

Tags: tikz-pic, chessboard

I am trying to create a states tree for demonstrating the N-Queens problem. I've managed to create a tree and display the chessboards in various states however there there is no gap between the nested nodes and the lines are drawn over the chessboard. I attempted to increase node size and node distance but this doesn't seem to be having an effect.

Here is my current latex for this:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfbaseshapes}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x4}{maxfield=d4}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={10mm}, thick, main/.style = minimum size=1em]
        \node (1) {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1},showmover=false]}
            child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb1},showmover=false]}}
            child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb2},showmover=false]}
                child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb2,Qc1},showmover=false]}}
                child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb2,Qc2},showmover=false]}}
            }
            child {node {$\dots$}
        };
        \node (2) [right=of 1] {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qb1},showmover=false]}
            child {node {$\dots$}
        };
        \node  [right=of 2] {$\dots$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which results in the following output:

[image]

Also as an aside, do I really need all of these packages to create a chessboard?
I'm using TexPad to edit this and it will no longer live compile while I'm using them all.

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chessfss}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage{pgfbaseshapes}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{chessboard}
```

Comment: regarding the asside: fontenc is unrelated (and you should load it) but from all the rest you only need chessboard, and you should load tikz.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with trees, but it seems that TikZ is totally ignoring the node sizes when placing the children.  The fact that they do not overlap is pure coincidence.  In fact, they **do** overlap since they have rather large white space borders.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for replying. I get the errors "File `pst-node.sty' not found" and "Emergency stop. (\fi ...)" in chessboard.sty when I remove the other packages. Adding back pst-node seems to resolve this but then I can no longer use live updates, which seems a bit odd.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks for replying, when I used `right of=` previously the nodes on the right were overlaping the other nodes.

Comment: why do you compile with latex instead of pdflatex? If you want to use latex you should ensure that pstricks is installed.

Comment: Unrelated to the question: The main difference between `right=of` and `right of=` is that the latter is deprecated and distances are calculated between node centers. With `right=of` (which is recommended), the distance is by default calculated between the edges of the nodes. Adding `on grid` means the distance is between node centers, if you need that.

Comment: I was was missing `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and was getting an error with `right=of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, `right=of ...` is correct, this is the syntax supported by the `positioning` library. To answer your question, you can use the `sibling distance` and the `level distance` keys to increase the gaps. I also played with `shorten >` and `shorten <` to adjust the connecting edges.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\storechessboardstyle{4x4}{maxfield=d4}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=25mm, level distance=25mm,
        thick,
        main/.style ={minimum size=1em}]        
        \path[shorten >=-1ex,shorten <=-1ex]
            node (1) {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1},showmover=false]}
            child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb1},showmover=false]}}
            child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb2},showmover=false]}
                child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb2,Qc1},showmover=false]}}
                child {node {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qa1,Qb2,Qc2},showmover=false]}}
            }
            child[shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex]  {node {$\dots$}
        };
        \path[shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex]
            node (2) [right=of 1] {\chessboard[tinyboard,style=4x4,setwhite={Qb1},showmover=false]}
            child {node {$\dots$}
        };
        \node  [right=of 2] {$\dots$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was aiming for.